# lua scripton haproxy 1.5

Tags: session, server, lua, haproxy

is lua scripting enabled on haproxy 1.5 , i checked this link: https://dx13.co.uk/articles/2016/05/27/selecting-a-haproxy-backend-using-lua/ it says Thankfully, HAProxy 1.6 introduces both variables and Lua scripting, which we can use to make things clearer and safer, if not particularly shorter. which means it s not supported before 1.6 . The documentation is insuffecient.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: can i write lua script for haproxy 1.5

Comment: If they added support for lua scripting in 1.6, you probably cannot use lua code in 1.5